# Need help for child processes in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec

I have a question which asks me to :
Write a program (in C under Linux!!!) that:

- Receives via the command line a command with its options and/or parameters
- Passes the command to a child process
- The child executes the command and returns the results to the parent process
- The father displays the results on the screen.

I managed to do this but the problem comes from the 2nd part of the question that I can't solve.

Part 2:
The program now receives as a parameter (via the command line) a shell script (shell file), i.e. a file containing a series of shell commands.
The file

- Does not contain any programming
- Is limited to the shell syntax seen in class (including pipes, redirects, command combinations, wildcards, ...)
  Each of the commands in the file must be executed by a child, which sends the results back to the father via the pipe and the father will display the results on the screen (as for part 1).

Here is my code for part 1:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc,char * argv[]){

//Création du pipe
        int descripteur[2];
        if(pipe(descripteur) != 0){
                return -1;
        }

//Création du fils

        pid_t pid_fils;
        pid_fils = fork();

        if(pid_fils ==-1){
                return -1;
        }

//Processus fils

        if (pid_fils == 0){
                close(descripteur[0]);
                if(dup2(descripteur[1],1) == -1){
                        printf("Erreur\n");
                        return -1;
                };
                if(dup2(descripteur[1],2) == -1){
                        printf("Erreur\n");
                        return -1;
                };
                close(descripteur[1]);
                if(execvp(argv[1],&argv[1]) == -1){
                        printf("Erreur\n");
                        return -1;
                };
        }
        
//Processus père
        
        else{
                char bufferHelper[256];
                close(descripteur[1]);
                int nbBit;

                while((nbBit = read(descripteur[0], bufferHelper, sizeof(bufferHelper))) !=0){
                        write( 1, bufferHelper, nbBit);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid "defunct" processes, the father must wait() for the end of the child process. So, after the while/read() loop, call waitpid(). You will get the status of the child process.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the input file contains one shell command per line without any programming structures combining multiple lines (i.e. for, while, if...).

So, you need to open the file and read it line by line with for example [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). For each line you can execute "sh -c command line" doing fork/exec of the following for each lines: av[0] = "sh", av[1]="-c", av[2] = cmdline, av[3] = NULL.

Or you can call [system()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) which does the same internally.

Through another pipe, you can also pass the content of the file as input to the child process which executes a shell.

Comment: Can strtok() be used to read the script lines?

Comment: Of course but the program is going to be complicated as a command line may contain quotes, double quotes (e.g echo "display me") and many other tokens like comments (i.e. # ...). As it is an exercise, I think you don't need to go into such a complicated command line analysis. Doing fork/exec of the following for each line will do the job: av[0] = "sh", av[1]="-c", av[2] = cmdline, av[3] = NULL

Comment: I see but I don't really understand how to integrate this into my code

Comment: I've just been told that you can't use fgets(),fopen(),fclose(),...
so how can I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer with another way to make it.